# What is meant by this Assembly Code?

Tags: assembly, x86, att

`jmp    *0x804a260(,%eax,4)`

Say, for example, `eax` holds 2. This will take 2 * 4 and add it to 0x804a260 giving you 0x804a268, and will jump to that location, correct?

Comment: Long time since I've done assembler, but from memory JMP is the jump command, so it looks to me to jump to a specific pointer/address and properly transfering the values of the eax register

Answer (score 3):

> jmp *0x804a260(,%eax,4)

The ATT syntax above is the same as the following in intel syntax:

```
jmp dword ptr [eax*4 + 0x804a260]
```

It computes the memory location `eax*4 + 0x804a260`, reads a dword from that location treating it like an address and jumps to that address.

Using your example, let's say `eax` is 2. The computed address is `0x804a268`. Furthermore, let's say at `0x804a268` it contains `0xbadf00d`. That means after doing the `jmp` the program counter `eip` will try to execute the next instruction at memory location `0xbadf00d`.